# How can I add more then one calendar from a same google account?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar, google-sync

I have my default google calendar synchronized with my iPod-touch, and I would like to add other calendars from the same account, is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose which calendars to sync by going to: http://www.google.com/calendar/iphoneselect

For more info, you can read Google's support doc about [CalDAV Calendar Sync](http://support.google.com/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151674).