# Syncing many Google Calendars under same account with iOS Calendar?

Tags: ipad, calendar, google-calendar

iPad CalenMob -calendar is able to sync many Google calendars of the same user such as Facebook-imported-calendar etc-etc. The iPad calendar for some reason only gets the default calendar, not other calendars in the same Google Account. So how can I get CalenMob -style features such as importing many calendars to iPad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > > > **This is the important site [here](https://www.google.com/calendar/iphoneselect). Below some misc instructions but you need the site if you use Google calendar with some iOS devices such as iPhone or iPad.**

**Basic Default-calendar -setup**

> You can decide the default calendar in Settings more [here](http://support.google.com/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138740), useful if you need to change it with different works, schools or universities for instance.

**Setting up many Google Calendars to iPad under your account**

> Please, preview this thread [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42529/how-can-i-add-more-then-one-calendar-from-a-same-google-account). You need nothing like CalenMob, use the default iOS -calendar and then decide which calendars to share with Apple products such as iPhone and iPad [here](https://www.google.com/calendar/iphoneselect). For some reason, Google calls it iPhone sync but in reality it handles also the iPad -calendar, perhaps also other Apple products?

**Why is it enough to set up just Google -calendars?**

> Because you can import other calendars such as Facebook-event-calendar, more [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lGa-K2A9UNs), to Google Calendars which you can later show with your Apple products such as iPad by the above instructions. Have Fun!